# create database from dump file in MySQL 5.0

Tags: mysql, database

i want to create database from dump file name "db_ehr.sql" any one can help me to do so..

Comment: What platform are you running on? (Linux, windows, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your db_ehr.sql should look like:

```
# DATEI:    db_ehr.sql
# ZWECK:    Kommando-Datei für mysql
#           create dbname - ???
# GEBRAUCH: [eh@xx xx]$ mysql  -u root [-p] < db_ehr.sql

# ------ Create Database

USE mysql;

DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS dbname;

CREATE DATABASE dbname;

# ------ Grant Access

GRANT ALL ON dbname.* TO user@'host';

# ------ Create/Fill Tables
```

The user (root) should be allowed to create databases and the user granted access should have a password (IDENTIFIED BY)

Added evidence:

Reduced version of script above (which 'works' for me too):

```
DOS E:\proj\lang\sql\mysql\winxpsp3
type demo00.sql
USE mysql;
show databases;
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS demo;
CREATE DATABASE demo;
show databases;
```

Usage: redirection:

```
DOS E:\proj\lang\sql\mysql\winxpsp3
mysql -u root -p < demo00.sql
Enter password: 
Database
...
classicmodels
mysql
...

Database
...
classicmodels
demo
mysql
```

Usage: source

```
mysql -u root -p
...
Server version: 5.0.51b-community-nt MySQL Community Edition (GPL)
...
mysql> source demo00.sql
Database changed
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
...
| classicmodels      |
| mysql              |
...
+--------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
...
| classicmodels      |
| demo               |
| mysql              |
...
+--------------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I got instructive error messages, when I tried nasty things:

Trying it as user without necessary rights:

ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'eh'@'localhost' to database 'demo'

Trying to create demo twice:

ERROR 1007 (HY000): Can't create database 'demo'; database exists

Trying to create a database named 'not a name':

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
   'not a name' at line 1

So I'm buffled to hear that your experiments failed without some hint at the reason.

Comment: @Bilal: without further details (what you did, relevant parts of your script, error message, unexpected results, ...) it's your complain that 'is not working', because I can't understand/reproduce your problem(s).

Comment: No datbase is created                                               (0 row(s) affected)
Execution Time : 00:00:00:000
Transfer Time  : 00:00:00:000
Total Time     : 00:00:00:000

Answer (score 20):

in mysql console:

```
create database test;
use test;
source db_ehr.sql;
```

Comment: where should i place the db_ehr.sql file?

Comment: in windows: source c:\path\to\db_ehr.sql; in linux source /home/test/source db_ehr.sql;

Answer (score 4):

The file can be executed using mysql command-line console.

```
shell>mysql --user=user_name --password=user_password --host=host_name --port=port_number<db_ehr.sql
```

You can specify full path for the file, e.g. d:\dir1\db_ehr.sql

[mysql — The MySQL Command-Line Tool](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql.html)

Comment: but do read the dump file to find out what you'll be loading/overwriting