# Problem creating MySQL database from dump file

Tags: mysql, ms-access

I am attempting to follow the instructions found here: [create database from dump file in MySQL 5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535479/create-database-from-dump-file-in-mysql-5-0)  to create a mySQL database from a dump file.

I created the dump file from an access database using the MS Access to MySQL tool (described here: [How can I convert an MDB (Access) file to MySQL (or plain SQL file)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5722544/how-can-i-convert-an-mdb-access-file-to-mysql-or-plain-sql-file)).

However, when I follow the instructions in the first link, the resulting database has no tables. To be more specific, if I run the command `SHOW TABLES IN test_db;`, the output is `Empty set (0.01 sec)`.

I'm stumped on what my next troubleshooting step should be. Could there have been an issue when creating the dump file? If that occurred, how would I check it?

In case it matters, the MySQL server that I am attempting this on is running in a linux environment.

-edit in response to comments-
The dump file is created by the linked GUI wizard tool, but after that point, I run the three SQL lines from the first linked question:

```
create database test;
use test;
source /path_to_dump_file/dump_file.sql;
```

the output is a whole bunch of

`Query OK, 1 row affect (0.00 sec)`

That's the extent of it.

-edit2- Ok, I think I misunderstood one of the questions: here is the first several lines of the dump file sql code:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `movedb`;
USE `movedb`;

#
# Table structure for table 'County by Station'
#

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `County by Station`;

CREATE TABLE `County by Station` (
  `Polygon/Station` VARCHAR(255), 
  `Tributary or Water Body` VARCHAR(255), 
  `Latitude` DOUBLE NULL, 
  `Longitude` DOUBLE NULL, 
  `County` VARCHAR(255), 
  INDEX (`Polygon/Station`)
) ENGINE=myisam DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

SET autocommit=1;

#
# Dumping data for table 'County by Station'
#
```

this is preceded by a description of the export options in the GUI and followed by a bunch of `INSERT INTO...` code

Comment: Reduce your SQL file to a sample with just a few tables, with a few records each. Test that. If this doesn't work, add the SQL to your question, plus the commands you ran. And all output from these commands.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us the first lines of the sql file you generated. Make sure to show us at least one complete CREATE TABLE statement and a few INSERT statements.

Comment: @Andre I reduced my dump file to a single table with <500 records and got the same results. I've added the commands I'm running, but there isn't much. The MS Access to MySQL tool is just a GUI wizard that doesn't save or report what SQL commands it is running to create the dump file, so all I have to report is the three lines from the first linked question.